# Can't select the package body from other schema in Oracle 10.2.0.4

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, privileges

My user has the following privileges:

```
`GRANT CREATE SESSION to user1;
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE to user1;
GRANT SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to user1;
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY to user1;
GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE to user1;
GRANT EXECUTE ANY TYPE to user1;
GRANT ALTER SESSION to user1;`
```

I can't get the package body runnig the following query from user1:

```
    SELECT owner, name, text, line FROM sys.DBA_source WHERE type='PACKAGE BODY'         
         AND owner NOT IN ('SYS')   AND owner = 'USER2'  AND name = 'MY_PKG'
```

But when I run a query from another user who has all the privileges, I can get the package body.

This issue was reproduced only on one server (Oracle 10.2.0.4).

Tell me please what privileges are missing. Or if it's not about privileges, tell me what to do to make it work.

Comment: What does "you can't" mean? Query returns nothing, or it raises an error? **a)** If it returns nothing then no rows in DBA_SOURCE satisfy WHERE conditions, **b)** if there's an error - which one?

Comment: Query returns nothing. But when i run this query from user with all privileges, i can get the package body. Does this mean that there are rows in DBA_SOURCE satisfy WHERE condition?

Comment: Hello @Yuliya

There is only one reason Oknow, why different user may become different result from dba_source. It's because they are connected to different databases. Please check instances with "select * from v$instance" for both users